# Does oauth issue a new token every request?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

If you request a token from the server (with the same credentials and within the lifespan of an old token) should it either:

- return a fresh token every time
- return the same token with a shorter lifespan
- something else / depends on

Is it depending on whether you use a refresh token?

Can you please reference the [OAuth 2 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) in your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

[The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) is a framework that allow a Resource Owner to CONSENT to allow [DELEGATION](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/OAuth%202.0%20NOT%20an%20Authentication%20protocol) of their permissions to access a Resource Server to another party (OAuth Client).

The [Authorization Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3) is performed by the OAuth Client and is fulfilled by the Authorization Server only after obtaining CONSENT from the Resource Owner by the Authorization Response (which includes a Access Token).

The [Access Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4) is a [Bearer Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) with a limited lifetime.

The [refresh Token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5), if used, by the client to requests a new access token by authenticating with the authorization server and presenting the refresh token. The client authentication requirements are based on the client type and on the authorization server policies.

The "same" Access Token is never returned or reused by the Authorization Server.

Reading and following the [Security Considerations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10) with any Authentication or Authorization Protocols is a must. Most breaches are caused by implementation errors rather than protocol errors.